# Allow updating column over trigger but prevent direct update of the same column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've got two tables which share some columns:

```
Table1:
+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  |
+----+----+----+
| a1 | b1 | c1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 |
| a3 | b3 | c3 |
+----+----+----+

Table2:
+----+----+----+----+
| E  | F  | A  | C  |
+----+----+----+----+
| e1 | f1 | a1 | c1 |
| e2 | f2 | a2 | c2 |
| e3 | f3 | a3 | c3 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

On `Table1` I have a trigger which updates column `A` in `Table2` after it is updated in `Table1`. But also I have a trigger on `Table2` which prevents direct updating of column `A` in `Table2`. The update should be allowed only over first trigger. The problem I am facing is that the second trigger fires even when I am updating the `Table2` through first trigger. 
Is there a way to prevent second trigger from fireing after update is done over first trigger?

Trigger1:

```
AFTER UPDATE AS 
   IF UPDATE (IMEPREZIME)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE t2
    SET A = i.A
    FROM DBO.Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN inserted i on t2.C = i.C
END
```

Trigger2:

```
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF UPDATE (A)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (A) and NOT EXISTS(SELECT A 
                from dbo.Table1 t1 
                where exists(select A 
                                from inserted i 
                                where t1.C= i.C ))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('DIRECT UPDATE OF COLUMN "A" IS FORBIDDEN', 16, -1)
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
END
```

Comment: What SQL Server version?

Comment: @DanGuzman Sorry, I didn't tought it was of great importance. I have edited my question, it's 2016

Comment: There are methods that with work in earlier SQL versions (like creating a dummy temp table) but those are more of a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016 and later, you can set a [`SESSION_CONTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql) value to short-circuit the second trigger.

```
AFTER UPDATE AS 
   IF UPDATE (IMEPREZIME)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC sp_set_session_context @key = N'FiredFromTrigger1', @value = 1;
    UPDATE t2
    SET A = i.A
    FROM DBO.Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN inserted i on t2.C = i.C;
    EXEC sp_set_session_context @key = N'FiredFromTrigger1', @value = NULL;
END;


AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF UPDATE (A)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'FiredFromTrigger1') AS bit) = 1 AND UPDATE (A) and NOT EXISTS(SELECT A 
                from dbo.Table1 t1 
                where exists(select A 
                                from inserted i 
                                where t1.C= i.C ))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('DIRECT UPDATE OF COLUMN "A" IS FORBIDDEN', 16, -1);
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: That's what I am talking about! Thanks boss!